# not all of my github files are uploading

Tags: git, github

I have done this a few times now and I do not know what the issue is now. I have a directory that is not uploading to my github, it is filled with mostly javascript files. There is not a .git file in there, I have also taken out the .git out of the main file several times and done the -rm command in cli. I have used the

```
git add -A

git add .
```

Does anyone know how to upload or how to upload ALL of the files in one go, cause it is not tracking them.

Comment: Could you provide an exact description what you did?

Comment: There is no errors. It just will not upload the directory. This directory is actually like 3 directories deep in the code.

Comment: Why did you remove the `.git` folder? That's the repo which you've deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps to push your code to `github`.

`1. git add .`

`2. git commit -m "your comment here"`

`3. git push -u origin branchname`

Comment: I do that with every repository that I have. This one is acting up you could say.

Answer (score 0):

```
git status --ignored
```

This is the command that I was needing. I was then able to track the missing files that were not being uploaded

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think there is `.gitignore` ? You need to search `.gitignore`, and notice there may be two `.gitignore`s and more.

After it, You can try commands below

- `git add *`
- `git status` and see if your files were commited.